# Handle the string

Tags: python-3.x, string

I have a problem with Python str which I've tried multiple variations, but none of them seem to work.
Here is my problem:

```
string = '18.0   8   307.0      130.0      3504.      12.0   70  1\t"chevrolet chevelle malibu"'
```

I want to handle this string, and get the return like this:

```
['18.0','8','307.0','130.0','3504.','12.0','70','1','"chevrolet chevelle malibu"']
```

or like this:

```
['18.0','8','307.0','130.0','3504.','12.0','70','1','chevrolet chevelle malibu']
```

I have tried to use re.complie(), but I failed to build a rule.
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the last value is always delimited by `'\t'` you can use this:

```
s = '18.0   8   307.0      130.0      3504.      12.0   70  1\t"chevrolet chevelle malibu"'

lst = [*s.split('\t')[0].split(), s.split('\t')[-1]]
print(lst)
```

Prints:

```
['18.0', '8', '307.0', '130.0', '3504.', '12.0', '70', '1', '"chevrolet chevelle malibu"']
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved with the following piece of code:

```
>>> string = '18.0   8   307.0      130.0      3504.      12.0   70  1\t"chevrolet chevelle malibu"'
>>> [y for (i, x) in enumerate(string.split('"')) for y in ([y.strip() for y in x.split()] if i % 2 == 0 else [x])]
['18.0', '8', '307.0', '130.0', '3504.', '12.0', '70', '1', 'chevrolet chevelle malibu']
```